# how to check strings using ng-if in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

In this html code I accessed list from angular code as options in select tag and defined `ng-model` for each select tag and using this `ng-model` I want to check them using `ng-if`.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
 <td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].loyality "  ng-model="loyality" required></select></td>
  <td><input type="number"  ng-model="value" required style="width:100px">   </td>
  <td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].period "  ng-model="period" required ></select></td>

   <div id="c6"  ng-if=" loyality || value || period " ><img   ng-src="images/Assets/WIP.png" /></div>
```

angular code in which list is defined

```
  var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngFlag']);

// create angular controller
  validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
         loyality: [{name:'points'},{name:'credits'}],
         value:0,
    period: [{name:'activity1'},{name:'activity2'}]
        }]      
};
```

Comment: If i get your question correct:
change ng-if to
    ng-if="item.locality || item.value || item.period

Comment: That `div` seems to have been placed directly within a `tr`. Either it needs placing within a `td` or your `tr` needs closing off before the `div`

Comment: It definitely needs to be inside the tr, since the select values are boud to attributes of the ng-repeat's inner scope.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
<td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item ininvoice.items[0].loyality "  ng-model="loyality" required></select></td>
<td><input type="number"  ng-model="value" required style="width:100px"></td>
<td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].period "  ng-model="period" required ></select></td>
 
 <td><a href ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
  <div id="c6"  ng-if=" loyality || value || period " ><img   ng-src="images/Assets/WIP.png" /></div>
 </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
      loyality: [{
        name: 'points'
      }, {
        name: 'credits'
      }],
      value: 0,
      period: [{
        name: 'activity1'
      }, {
        name: 'activity2'
      }]
    }, {
      loyality: [{
        name: 'points2'
      }, {
        name: 'credits2'
      }],
      value: 1,
      period: [{
        name: 'activity111'
      }, {
        name: 'activity222'
      }]
    }]
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="invoice_item in invoice.items">
        <td>
          <select ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in invoice_item.loyality" ng-model="invoice_item.loyality_v" required></select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" ng-model="invoice_item.value" required style="width:100px">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in invoice_item.period" ng-model="invoice_item.period_v" required></select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="c6" ng-if=" invoice_item.loyality_v || invoice_item.value || invoice_item.period_v ">
            <!--img ng-src="images/Assets/WIP.png" /-->SHOW ME
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <b>Trace:</b>
    <pre>
  invoice.items = {{invoice.items | json}}
  </pre>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```